# How get dynamic class name in Yii expression?

Tags: php, yii

The question is quite straight forward, but I guess answer isn't.

I have following syntax in my Yii application:

```
$model=\models\common\Recipe::getTableSchema()->columns;
```

I want to have dynamic class name each time this whole controller function is called. Like

```
$DynamicClass=$_GET['classname'];

$model=\models\common\$DynamicClass::getTableSchema()->columns;
```

But that does not work since the whole expression is not a string. Any idea how can I plugin dynamic classname into the above expression to get the table scheme dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in `php 5.3+` you can do:

```
 $dynamic_class='\\models\\common\\'.$_GET['classname'];
 $columns=$dynamic_class::getTableSchema()->columns;
```